# How to add string builder data to listview in android?

Tags: php, android, listview

I am getting data from  PHP server and i read it as string builder. Now i want to add it to listview . How can i do it? Here is my php data. I want to display it in Listview

```
private String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) {
        String line = "";
        StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        try {
            while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {

                total.append(line+"\n");
                    }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.v("sat", ""+e);
        }
```

And result is:

```
["A","B","C","D","E","F","G"]
```

Now  How can i add this data to listview?

Comment: use adapter in android

Comment: @N5, i knew it very well already. my question is how to add this data to adapter? how to remove ", [ and split it ?

Comment: its array , you can convert it arraylist and use in adapter like arrayadapter , why u wanna slipt it?

Comment: You get it as json array and then convert it into list of string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple array adapter try this:

```
ArrayList<String>arr_list= new ArrayList<String>();
String str=strbuilder.toString();       

String[] str1=str.split(",");
for(int i=0;i<str1.length;i++){

    arr_list.add(str1[i]);
}

System.out.println("values=="+str1);
System.out.println("arr_list=="+arr_list);


        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                      android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,  arr_list);

            // Assign adapter to ListView
             listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Here strbuilder is your StringBuilder.

Comment: nice. but how to add my data to arrayadapter? that is my questions now

Comment: your data String[] arr={"A","B","C","D","E","F","G"};  this only right

Comment: what is your json response please add your json response

Comment: yes ofcourse Vijay. then i read  it as stringbuilder. how to convert it to array??? pls say me

Answer (score 0):

If `["A","B","C","D","E","F","G"]` is of `String[] values`

then use simple list view adapter

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
              android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.<textviewname>, values);

    // Assign adapter to ListView
     listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

**convertStreamToStringArrayList**  method...

```
  public ArrayList<String> convertStreamToString(InputStream is) {
                ArrayList<String> data=new ArrayList<String>();
                String line;
                BufferedReader info = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
                try {
                    while ((line = info.readLine()) != null) {

                            data.add(line);
                            }
                    return data;
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.v("sat", ""+e);
                }
                return null;
               }
```

and you can use this method like:

```
 listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
               android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,  convertStreamToString(YourStream)));
```

**Or**

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,convertStreamToString(YourStream));

listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

**or**

```
ArrayList<String> data=convertStreamToString(YourStream);
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,data);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```